# Set Text Combobox in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why can't I assign `Text` on a combobox? It isn't visible:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="status">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}" Width="130" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox Text="111" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" Height="Auto" 
                                              SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged"
                                              Width="130">
.....etc.
```

Comment: I Guess Text is not a valid Property in this context. Try using Content. Hope this works out

Answer (score 0):

If ComboBox is not [`IsEditable="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx) you can only set Items existing in the ItemsCollection. Make sure your binded name property value is the same as in Items.

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding name}">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="111" />
    </ComboBox.Items>            
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer for your special case. Does it work now?